# CAML Query works on hardcoded value, but not on variable

Tags: development, caml-query

I am really new to SharePoint, and I came across an issue that is driving me crazy. I am trying to use CAML Query to get a specific list item. My query works on hard coded condition, but not when I pass in the value using a variable.
Here is my code:

```
foreach (SPGroup group in groups)
    {

        queryTeams.Query = @"<Where>
                                 <Eq>       
                                    <FieldRef Name='GroupTeams' />
                                      <Value Type='User'>" + group.Name + @"</Value>
                                  </Eq>
                               </Where>
                           "; // group.Name = Pharmacist Assistants                         

            SPListItemCollection itemsTeams = listTeams.GetItems(queryTeams);

            if (itemsTeams.Count > 0)
            {
                //do stuff
            }
```

And here is the hard coded query that returns values:

```
queryTeams.Query = @"<Where>
                       <Eq>
                           <FieldRef Name='GroupTeams' />
                             <Value Type='User'>Pharmacist Assistants</Value>
                        </Eq>
                      </Where>";
```

Please help me figure out what am I doing wrong.

Comment: In the first CAML query (the "dynamic" one) the new line just before "WHERE" is actually present in the real code or just a refuse ? Also - have you checked that group.Name is indeed equal to "Pharmacist Assistants"?

Comment: I just deleted the new line, please see the edited code. Yes, the group.Name is "Pharmacist Assistants". Thank you.

Comment: Write your query in one single line, that will help you understand where you are going wrong. You can format once you have figured out the issue. Possibly `@` is causing issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

might sound silly but have you tried:

**EDIT**

```
foreach (SPGroup group in groups)
    {
        SPQuery queryTeams = new SPQuery();

        queryTeams.Query = @"<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='GroupTeams' /><Value Type='User'>" + group.Name.ToString() + @"</Value></Eq></Where>"; 

            SPListItemCollection itemsTeams = listTeams.GetItems(queryTeams);

            if (itemsTeams.Count > 0)
            {
                //do stuff
            }
```

you could make the SPQuery object global if you wanted to (used in many places) but within the foreach you must create a new object recursivly! like so:

global varible:

```
private SPQuery queryTeams;
```

within method:

```
foreach (SPGroup group in groups)
    {
        queryTeams = new SPQuery();

        queryTeams.Query = @"<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='GroupTeams' /><Value Type='User'>" + group.Name.ToString() + @"</Value></Eq></Where>"; 

            SPListItemCollection itemsTeams = listTeams.GetItems(queryTeams);

            if (itemsTeams.Count > 0)
            {
                //do stuff
            }
```

Comment: When I look at query.Teams using the debugger, this is what I get:{<Where>
                                                             <Eq>       
                                                            <FieldRef Name='GroupTeams' />
                                                                <Value Type='User'>Pharmacist Assistants</Value>
                                                            </Eq></Where>} and I get the same sequence when I hard code the "Pharmacist Assistants" part.

Comment: just ammended the code, could you try that?

Comment: So I just figured it out. I had to create a new instance of the SPQuery class, before I would try to use my QueryTeams object.

Comment: ali SharePoint, I see this is your solution too. Thank you very much for your help :)

Comment: yes for each call! lol just beat you to it ;)